# Does data storage on private Ethereum blockchain come at no cost?

Tags: ether, private-blockchain, database

Knowing that:

1. In a private Ethereum blockchain, I can have no value of ether and basically allocate as much ether as I want.
2. Storing data on a public blockchain is a costly affair

If I were to conclude from those that since I'm using a private Ethereum blockchain, I can store as much data as I want?
What will happen from latency standpoint?
If I have 1000 devices sending data per second which I need to store on private blockchain with 3 organizations, how should I go about that?

Comment: The cost will be the servers, electricity and bandwidth needed. There are no free lunches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off having a traditional DB where those 3 organizations **will authenticate** and send their data, because:

- at the present moment, the **ethereum network doesn't support 1k tx/s** (not even close may I say, being close to 15 tx/s)
- scaling SQL DBs and NoSQL DBs to support 1k tx/s is an already solved issue
- given that you know and approve these companies's access to your DB, you don't need a trustless environment
- if you want these companies to audit the data, you can give them full access to a replica of your main DB
- there's absolutely no benefit you'd get from using a blockchain for 3 companies
- this solution might actually be safer, because otherwise, each of these companies could buy some mining rigs and perform a [51% attack](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/1/51-attack.asp), while you assume the network is safe.

So, to answer you question: yes, you can have a private ethereum instance, with no gas costs, but it would most probably bring you more headaches than issues solved.

Comment: The reason why we are adopting Blockchain is for trust, immutability more than anything else.